# Parsing DSA key with golang into tls config object

Tags: go, ssl, apache-kafka, private-key, dsa

I have a set of a DSA client private key, client- and  and a CA certificate files, which I would like to use with the kafka-go library. I have been trying to parse the files but have been unsuccessful. The aformentioned key and certificate files are correct, as they are being used in other places, written in Javascript though. I have been trying to parse them in the following manner:

```
func NewTLSConfig(clientCertFile, clientKeyFile, caCertFile string) (*tls.Config, error) {
    tlsConfig := tls.Config{}
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(clientCertFile, clientKeyFile
    ...
```

Where the string inputs are correct file paths. At this point I get the following error:

> tls: failed to parse private key

which is coming from the **parsePrivateKey** function of the tls library. When checking the the function's input, it seems to be fine.

```
cert.PrivateKey, err = parsePrivateKey(keyDERBlock.Bytes)
```

The **keyDERBlock** object is populated, it has a proper type and bytes. What could be the issue? Thank you!

I have created a small [Github repo](https://github.com/donfrigo/dsa-error) to illustrate the issue.

Comment: we can't easily debug incomplete snippets.  Provide a complete verifiable example.

Comment: The function expects file paths as an input, not sure how to reproduce it with go playground for example. I could create a simple git repo, that illustrates the problem though :)

Comment: a fine idea.  It would be good to include the code here.  I think there's a good chance you discover the solution while you try to put together a minimal reproduction of the error - I usually do.

Comment: Yes, fair point. I have created a small repo here: https://github.com/donfrigo/dsa-error. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, has anyone found a solution for this? Does Go TLS just not support DSA? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been solved by using RSA keys instead of DSA.